# Not getting the right fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to create a subscription feature in my Django site where a user enters his name and email and clicks the 'Subscribe' button. I have written this code in the subscribe.html form but it keeps showing the main post form which is used to write the blog post. Can anyone help me fix this?

Here are the relevant codes.

**forms.py**

Subscribe form  **(Please note that when I type http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscribe/, I see the 'Title' and 'Body' of the post form but not the Name and Email of the subscribe form.)**

```
class SubscribeForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
       model = Subscribe
       fields = ('name', 'email')

       widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'email': forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'emailinputclass'}))
        }

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        # fields = ('author','title', 'body',)
        fields = ('title', 'body')

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'editable medium-editor-textarea postcontent'}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class SubscribeView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Subscribe
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'blog/subscribe.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('subscribe')
```

**Templates**

Subscribe.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Join my List</h1>

    <form method="POST" class="subscribe-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
    </form>

    <script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Postnew.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <h1>New post</h1>

    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>

    <script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
  path('subscribe/', SubscribeView.as_view(), name='subscribe'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Subscribe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank= False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 60, blank = False)
```

I was expecting to see the right widgets of the subscribe form but the widgets of the post new form appear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is that ```{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
``` supposed to be in views.py?

Comment: You got the widgets of the form which you passed in your view. Here, in your 'SubscribeView'  you use `form_class = PostForm`, that's why you are getting that form widgets('title', 'body') if you want `SubscribeForm` widgets ('Name', 'Email') then use `form_class = SubscribeForm`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. It's working now....was a careless mistake on my part.